# To know last insert data on mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have some questions about **syntax on mysql**. Is it possibly to know last insert data on mysql with **sql** command in terminal or not? If possibly just write me thanks for all hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into table (field) values (value);
SELECT @iLastId := LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get last inserted ID using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: Thanks lot!! The help so much. And also documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT user_id FROM my_users_table ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 0,1';
```